# Symfony MAILER_DSN SMTP authentication error with IONOS: Expected response code "250" but got code "530", with message "530 Authentication required

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, smtp, sendmail

I am working on a Symfony project and trying to configure the `MAILER_DSN` in the `.env` file to send emails using the SMTP server of my email provider, `IONOS`.

I have set up the `MAILER_DSN` with the correct server name (smtp.ionos.fr), port number (465), encryption (ssl), and authentication mode (login). I have also verified that the username (contact@domain.fr) and password (blabla@2021) are correct.

However, when I try to send an email, I get the following error:

> Expected response code "250" but got code "530", with message "530
> Authentication required".

[image]

Here's my .env file :

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://smtp.ionos.fr:465?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=ccontact@domain.fr&password=blabla@2021
```

I have already tried changing the authentication mode to cram-md5 and plain, using a different port number (587), and verifying that the SMTP server name and port number are correct. I have also checked if two-factor authentication is enabled for my email account, but it is not.

What else can I try to resolve this SMTP authentication error with Symfony and IONOS? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you convert your password? it is not allowed to use special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using symfony 6 with ionos server (in france !), the MAILER_DSN should be :

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://email@domain.fr:password@smtp.ionos.fr:465
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved it changing the deprecated bundle "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" by the new one "symfony/mailer". Implementation is very similar. (I'm using symonfy 5.4)

With the same MAILER_DSN string, it works with the new bundle. I don't know the reason. Probably some new  requirement of the ionos servers.

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://mymailaccount%40mydomain.com:password@smtp.ionos.es:587
```

Comment: Hello, i'm using symfony 6,  symfony/mailer is the default bundle . Thank you for your help, i put the answer that worked for me .